# Did Facebook change access_token style?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I think Facebook changed access_token style or I am doing something really wrong?

URL Linter is not working anymore.

Can someone confirm that change?

URL Linter:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have just transitioned to OAuth 2.0 and phased out OAuth 1.0 is my understanding. It's been on their [road map](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/497/) for a while.

The access_token is now encrypted.

Comment: Can the application somehow decrypt the access_token ?

Comment: I'm still getting up to speed with it myself, for canvas apps it looks like you need SSL. I *think* implementations using social plugins are unaffected. More [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) on signed requests, says you can decode request, not sure about token.